# Unable to reset

Tags: windows

First I want to reset my windows 10. But here show me a window looking below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdxPQ.png)

Then I went to cmd and write "reagentc /enable"
But found this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG9jC.png)

I tried several method. But, I could not fix this problem.
How to fix ?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether you need to save your data.

Options can be viewed here

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options